# How to get type inference from Firestore DocumentSnapshot exists

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

The following is a pretty common scenario for me:

```
type SomeDocument = {
  foo: string;
};

export async function getSomeDocument(): Promise<SomeDocument> {
  const doc = await db
    .collection("some")
    .doc("document")
    .get();

  if (!doc.exists) throw new Error("Missing some document");

  return doc.data();
}
```

Typescript doesn't allow this because the doc.data() return type is `DocumentSnapshot | undefined`. Somehow I feel that Typescript should be able to know that doc.data() is going to return a DocumentSnapshot because of the doc.exists check that preceded it.

Would this be possible using correct type annotation in the current version of Typescript?

I currently solve this by casting the return statement with `as SomeDocument`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already identified exactly what you're supposed to do - `return doc.data() as SomeDocument`.  TypeScript isn't going to allow one thing to simply become another thing that's not naturally part of its inheritance or implemented interfaces.  You have to be explicit about casting the type in this case.  Accessing the `exists` property doesn't change the situation, from the perspective of TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this! I thought the problem stemmed from the `| undefined` part, but it makes sense that Typescript wouldn't cast DocumentSnapshot to another type automatically.